# Cakephp Unidentified Index problem

Tags: php, cakephp, error-handling

Hi been trying to get this to work for ages,

i have a deals controller

```
<?php
class DealsController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Deals';
    var $helpers = array('HTML', 'Javascript', 'Form', 'Time', 'Ajax');
    var $components = array('RequestHandler', 'Session', 'Cookie');
    var $uses = array('Deal', 'City', 'Partner');

    function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();

        if(strpos($this->here, 'admin')){
            $this->layout = 'admin';
        }

    }

    function view($id = null) {
        if (!$id) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid deal', true));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->set('deal', $this->Deal->read(null, $id));
    }

    function by_city($CityID = null)
{
    $city = $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('City.id' => $CityID),
        'limit' => 1
     );
    $this->set('city',$city);


    $this->Retailer->recursive = -1;
    $this->paginate = array(
        'conditions' => array('Deal.city_id' => $CityID),
        'order' => array('Deal.start'=>'desc'),
        'limit' => 3
     );
    $this->set('deals',$this->paginate());

}
```

and the by_city view is :

```
<h3>More Deals from <?php echo $city['City']['city'];?></h3>
```

Now when i run this i am getting a "unidentified index City" notice

when i run var_dump it says that theres an array City and 'city' has a value aswell which sounds to me like the controller has passed this

i'm lost now lol

All help appreciated, if you  need more info just ask :)

Edit: Changed code - its still not identifying the variable City

here is the var_dump to show that the controller is passing it:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Deal"]=>
    array(15) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["... this part of is fine so ill hide this part of the var_dump
    }
    ["City"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["city"]=>
      string(7) "Glasgow"
    }
  }
}
```

as you can see $city['City']['city'] is being passed. PS i will change the name of this field ;)

Thanks
Dave

Comment: HAHAHAHA like ufos?^^ you probably mean "undefined"...

Comment: can you post the output of var_dump($deals) ?

Comment: For what it's worth, you may want to consider following the naming conventions for the models. If you have a table named cities, instead of using city for the field, you should use name. Then you can query on City.name instead of City.city.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use CakePHP, you should follow its way to retrieve data. Change your code to this:

> ```
> function by_city($CityID = null)
> {
>     $this->paginate = array(
>       'conditions' => array('City.id' => $CityID),
>       'order' => array('Deal.start'=>'desc'),
>       'limit' => 3
>     );
>     $deals = $this->paginate();
>     $city = $this->City->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('City.id'=>$CityID)));
>     $this->set(compact('deals','city'));
> }
> ```

Edit: I see what you want to do now, check the code above ;)

Comment: assuming recursive is >= 0 - otherwise it would be better to use containable here

Comment: He seems to be new to cake, so I just show him the basic stuffs first. But yes, Containable is definitely better.

Comment: yeah :) of course. i still laugh my head off, though. lets call them UFI - unidentified flying index^^ no offense, bro.

Comment: just to clarify all i want is the city name from the city table, the rest of the array is from the deals table, is this still the way forward ? :)

Comment: Yes, it should have all the data you need. You can debug($deals); in the view to check the content. It can be optimized a little bit better, but let's just leave it at that until you learn about Containable.